# html: why is my table not 100% of the width?

Tags: html, asp.net

I am trying to show a table that stretches the entire width of the container (which is body)

I am trying this:

```css
body {
    width: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    background: green;
}

.mainHeader{
    height: 150px;
    background-color:white;
}

.table-fullWitdh {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-fullWitdh">
    <tr>
        <td class="mainHeader table-fullWitdh">
            hi
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But the result is not a 100 percent width in the table, this is the result:

[image]

You can clearly see that the table does not stretch over the whole screen. why is that?

Comment: but I did set the container to be 100 vh, which is the whole page ( as visible by the green)

Comment: You set it to 100vh which is the view height. Think you meant 100vw!

Comment: oh thank you u ofcrouse were right!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width: 100%` style rule doesn't mean 100% of the *visible width of the page*, it means 100% of the width of the *containing element*.  In this case the containing element is the `<body>` element, which has a restricted width:

```
width: 100vh;
```

Remove that restriction and the `<body>` is *by default* 100% the width of the viewport, allowing the table to expand with it:

```html
<body>
    <table class="table-fullWitdh">
        <tr>
            <td class="mainHeader table-fullWitdh">
                hi
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

<style type="text/css">

    body {
        padding: 0;
        background: green;
    }

    .mainHeader{
        height: 150px;
        background-color:white;
    }

    .table-fullWitdh {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Yup, that did fix is. However: I dont understand how 100vh restricted it but the green showed that it streched all the way AAND:
There is still a a padding right, left and top... (5px maybe max, but where is that comming from?) thank you!

Comment: @inno: This is a good opportunity for you to use your browser's debugging tools.  In Chrome, right-click on the element and select "Inspect".  In the DOM explorer you can select elements and observe the styling rules which affect them, including the built-in user agent rules for the browser.  In this case note any `padding` or `margin` of the `<body>` element.

Comment: yes! this is actually a good idea thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace `vh`(viewport-height) with `vw`(viewport-width)

```html
<body>
    <table class="table-fullWitdh">
        <tr>
            <td class="mainHeader table-fullWitdh">
                hi
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

<style type="text/css">

    body {
        width: 100vw; // vh(viewport-height) -> vw(viewport-width)
        padding: 0;
        background: green;
    }

    .mainHeader{
        height: 150px;
        background-color:white;
    }

    .table-fullWitdh {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```